# How to repair this plastic picnic table?

Tags: repair, plastic, table

We've had this plastic picnic table for years and the surface is really cracking up. The frame seems solid yet. Is there a cost effective way to repair this table to get a few more years out of it?

[image: picnic table]

Closeup of bench
[image: Closeup of bench]

Closeup of top
[image: Closeup of top]

Comment: If it's still structurally solid, and the crazing is just cosmetic, just cover it with a plastic tablecloth. Anything you used to make it stronger, such as a sheet of plywood or plastic glazing, would cost a large fraction of a new picnic table, and likely would not last long.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Or fiberglass fabric and epoxy, but both are expensive.

Comment: spray acrylic (aka better-quality spray paint) will add a new thin plastic layer to the surface. Keep it out of UV as much as you can to slow the degradation of the plasticizer, which a coat of paint will also help ameliorate
.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because furniture repair is off topic.

Comment: I am curious where this question should have been asked?

Answer (score 1):

Worst case, if the cosmetic coverings aren't suitable, get some pressure treated 1x and screw/bolt it to the plastic surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Buy an acrylic sheet, either transparent, translucent or a bold colour, cut it to size, and either glue it or screw it on to the existing top. It would come in various thicknesses, and 5 or 6 mm would do the job for a good few years to come. File the edges, so there's no sharp bits to hurt folk.